# Ad-hoc validation + Dependency Injection

Tags: playframework, dependency-injection, playframework-2.4

I'm using Play 2.4 with Java. I created an object as simple as this:

```
public class User {

    @Constraints.Required
    public String email;
    public String password;

    public String validate() {
    }
}
```

I use this object to create a form in my controller:

```
public MyController extends Controller {

    public Result index() {
        return ok(mypage.render(Form.form(User.class)));
    }

    public Result submit() {
        Form<User> userForm = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, I've got a service that I would like to inject in this object, and call one of its methods, such as:

```
public class User {

    @Inject MyService myService;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String email;
    public String password;

    public String validate() {
        return myService.authenticate(email, password);
    }
}
```

Doing this, I get a `RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` when the bindFromRequest() method is called. There is a NullPointerException when I try to call myService's method `authenticate`. **Isn't the service injected properly?**

Is there something special to do in that particular case - the fact that the `validate()` method gets automatically called when the request in bound to a form object?

Comment: I we saying about service in play meaning can you just create object in class user as:

    private static MyService service = new MyService();

and later invoke method in user class?

BTW If you want validate email and password from request you can use bindFromRequest method

Comment: Above link contains an answer you are looking for.

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you